# Show $\max(p_1-1,\frac{p_1\log p_1}{4\log(n/p_1)})+\max(p_2-1,\frac{p_2\log p_2}{4\log(n/p_2)})+\min(p_1,p_2)\ge\max(p-1,\frac{p\log p}{4\log(2n/p)})$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm struggling with the following problem.

**STATEMENT:**

Given real numbers $n,p,p_1,p_2 \ge 1$ such that $p = p_1 + p_2$ and $p < n$, prove:

$\max(p_1-1,\frac{p_1\log p_1}{4\log(n/p_1)})+\max(p_2-1,\frac{p_2\log p_2}{4\log(n/p_2)})+\min(p_1,p_2)\ge\max(p-1,\frac{p\log p}{4\log(2n/p)})$

$$\max\left(p_1-1, \frac{p_1\log p_1}{4\log\frac{n}{p_1}}\right) + \max\left(p_2-1, \frac{p_2\log p_2}{4\log\frac{n}{p_2}}\right) + \min(p_1,p_2) \ge \max\left(p-1,\frac{p\log p}{4\log\frac{2n}{p}}\right)$$

**TRIED:**

I've checked in Sage that this holds for $1 \le n \le 1000$ and every valid combination of $p_1$ and $p_2$.

I've tried using Jensen's inequality for $f(x) = \max\left(x-1, \frac{x\log x}{4\log\frac{n}{x}}\right)$, i.e.

$$\max\left(p_1-1, \frac{p_1\log p_1}{4\log\frac{n}{p_1}}\right) + \max\left(p_2-1, \frac{p_2\log p_2}{4\log\frac{n}{p_2}}\right) \ge 2\max\left(\frac{p}{2}-1, \frac{\frac{p}{2}\log \frac{p}{2}}{4\log\frac{2n}{p}}\right),$$

but I don't know what to do wtih $\min(p_1, p_2)$.

I've also tried analyzing several cases, depending on which of the expressions achieves maximum. For each of the cases, I've equated the first derivative with 0, but the equations get quite cumbersome. (I couldn't get a closed-form solution for them.)

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to approach the problem!

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Hi, @Shaun do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is not really my area. The problem with the current title is that it describes every question about minimalisation here.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the title... I hope it's more descriptive like this.

Comment: Yes, that's better; I've added "show" because titles containing only $\rm\LaTeX$ are advised against for technical reasons.